# What is the best way to vectorize/optimize this python code?

Tags: python, optimization, vectorization

I am calculating 48 derived ***pandas*** columns by iterating and calculating each column at a time but need to speed up the process. What is the best way to do this to make it faster and more efficent. Each column calculates the closing price as a percentage of the period's (T, T-1, T-2 etc) high and low price.

The code I am currently using is:

```
#get last x closes as percentage of period high and low
for i in range(1, 49, 1):
    df.loc[:,'Close_T_period_'+str(i)] = ((df['BidClose'].shift(i).values 
    - df['BidLow'].shift(i).values)/          
    (df['BidHigh'].shift(i).values - df['BidLow'].shift(i).values))
```

Input dataframe sample:

```
                     BidOpen  BidHigh   BidLow  BidClose  AskOpen  AskHigh   AskLow  AskClose   Volume
Date                                                                                                  
2019-09-27 09:00:00  1.22841  1.22919  1.22768   1.22893  1.22850  1.22927  1.22777   1.22900  12075.0
2019-09-27 10:00:00  1.22893  1.23101  1.22861   1.23058  1.22900  1.23110  1.22870   1.23068  16291.0
2019-09-27 11:00:00  1.23058  1.23109  1.22971   1.23076  1.23068  1.23119  1.22979   1.23087  10979.0
2019-09-27 12:00:00  1.23076  1.23308  1.23052   1.23232  1.23087  1.23314  1.23062   1.23241  16528.0
2019-09-27 13:00:00  1.23232  1.23247  1.23163   1.23217  1.23241  1.23256  1.23172   1.23228  14106.0
```

Output dataframe sample:

```
                     BidOpen  BidHigh   BidLow  BidClose  ...  Close_T_period_45  Close_T_period_46  Close_T_period_47  Close_T_period_48
Date                                                      ...                                                                            
2019-09-27 09:00:00  1.22841  1.22919  1.22768   1.22893  ...           0.682635           0.070796           0.128940           0.794521
2019-09-27 10:00:00  1.22893  1.23101  1.22861   1.23058  ...           0.506024           0.682635           0.070796           0.128940
2019-09-27 11:00:00  1.23058  1.23109  1.22971   1.23076  ...           0.774920           0.506024           0.682635           0.070796
2019-09-27 12:00:00  1.23076  1.23308  1.23052   1.23232  ...           0.212500           0.774920           0.506024           0.682635
2019-09-27 13:00:00  1.23232  1.23247  1.23163   1.23217  ...           0.378882           0.212500           0.774920           0.506024
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Consider to update your question explaining better your problem, what your code is supposed to do and adding some input/output example.

Comment: Thanks Fabio. I can provide a sample of the pandas input and output but how to I share/paste that here please?

Comment: You can print the head or a significant number of rows of the dataset, for example using: `print(df.head())`. Paste the result here formatted as code.

Comment: Added input and output tail samples as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

### Short Answer (faster implementation)

the following code is 6x times faster:

```
import numpy as np

def my_shift(x, i):
    first = np.array([np.nan]*i)
    return np.append(first, x[:-i])

result = ((df2['BidClose'].values - df2['BidLow'].values)/(df2['BidHigh'].values - df2['BidLow'].values))
for i in range(1, 49, 1):
    df2.loc[:,'Close_T_period_'+str(i)] = my_shift(result, i)
```

### Long Answer (explanation)

The two main bottleneck issues in your code are:

1. In every iteration you recalculate the same values, the only
   difference is that, every times, are shifted differently;
2. pandas shift operation is very slow for your purpose.

so my code simply manage the two issues. Basically I calculate the result just one time and I use the loop only for shifting (Issues #1 improved), and I implemented my own shift function that append in front of the original array `i` NaN values and cut the last `i`.

#### Execution time

With a dataframe with 5000 rows the time benchmark give:

```
42 ms ± 1.79 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

with my solution I obtained:

```
7.62 ms ± 140 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

### UPDATE

I tried to implement a solution with apply:

```
result = ((df2['BidClose'].values - df2['BidLow'].values)/(df2['BidHigh'].values - df2['BidLow'].values))
df3 = df.reindex(df2.columns.tolist() +[f'Close_T_period_{i}' for i in range(1, 2000)], axis=1)
df3.iloc[:, 9:] = df3.iloc[:, 9:].apply(lambda row: my_shift(result, int(row.name.split('_')[-1])))
```

In my test this solution seems a slightly slower then the first one.

Comment: Thanks for this Fabio. Is this something that could be completely vectorised removing the 'for' iteration or is that not possible or appropriate here?

Comment: I don't have in mind a way to vectorize, the problem is that you create a new column on every loop.

Comment: Ok. I having been trying to vectorise it but couldn't quite work out how to. It's sort of comforting to hear that that's because it's not possible. Anyway, 6x faster is good for me. Thanks again for your help Fabio :-)

Comment: Just one more thing Fabio - do you think there could be any further improvement in your solution here by trying to use 'apply' instead of the 'for' loop or not really?

Comment: I updated my answer using apply, I don't see performance improvement and the first solution looks more clear. P.S: consider to put a +1 and accept my answer if it was helpful for you :)

Comment: Thanks again. I have +1 your answer but have less than 15 reputation!

Comment: Fabiol - Now I am able to +1 your helpful answer. Many thanks again